# Publish a Sidekiq schedule job through Private Pub in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, private-pub

I am using 'Sidekiq' to schedule reminder about any task on given time. Its working perfect. Now i want to append it to notify on my navbar, for it i am using 'Private Pub' to publish the reminder message.
 Here is code of Sidekiq Worker.

```
class ReminderWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker

def perform(args)
 reminder = Reminder.find(args['id'])
 reminder.activate = true
 PrivatePub.publish_to("reminder", message: reminder)
 reminder.save
 end
end
```

and inside "application.js" i am using alert for testing but it is not working.

```
 PrivatePub.subscribe("reminder", function(data, channel) {
 return alert('Remarks ='+ data.message.remarks);
```

});

Am i missing some thing? As it is possible to publish data through Private  Pub in rb file accourding to Ryan http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub?autoplay=true

Answer (score 0):

This gem has been updated last time three years ago and seems not maintained.
Maybe it's better to use newest rails solution like ActionCabble? https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable

I found this issue, that proofs that ActionCabble can be integrated to ActiveJob or other background workers:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22897